# how to disable button until a request is completed

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I have a like button and once a user clicks on it, the button should only allow one click (i.e allow only one like per user)

```
<button disabled={buttonState} onClick={() => {like(item)}}>
   <Icon size={30} /> 
</button>
```

**Function:**

```
const [ buttonState, setButtonState] = useState(false)

const like = async (item) => {
    const id = item.id
    const likes = item.likes
    const userAdd = item.userAdd
    var count = 1;
    var user = userAddress
    
    if(userAdd.includes(userAddress)) return
    if(!count || count > 1 || count < 1 || !user) return
    setButtonState(true)
    await client
    .patch(id)
    .inc({likecount: count})
    .insert('after', 'userAddAddress[-1]',[user])
    .commit().then(() => {
        setButtonState(false)
    })
}
```

In the above code,
on spamming like button, the user can like 2 times.
The button click takes a few sec to get disabled, so that on spamming it allows multiple clicks.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? It looks like it should run just fine. I've used similar code and it worked just fine.

I'd say make sure disabled={true} works, then log your state changes and see if there are any issues.

The answer by Huynq is good too, I would use useRef in this situation instead of useState.

Comment: @Displayname disable state works but it takes 1-2 secs to change the state. So, by that time if user spams the like button, it increments to 2.
The below answer by hunq is making the button disabled so that user can't even like one time also

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a ref to check user can `like` or not

```
const [ buttonState, setButtonState] = useState(false);
const disabledRef = useRef(false);

const like = async (item) => {
    if (disabledRef.current) return;
    const id = item.id
    const likes = item.likes
    const userAdd = item.userAdd
    var count = 1;
    var user = userAddress
    
    if(userAdd.includes(userAddress)) return
    if(!count || count > 1 || count < 1 || !user) return
    setButtonState(true);
    disabledRef.current = true;
    await client
    .patch(id)
    .inc({likecount: count})
    .insert('after', 'userAddAddress[-1]',[user])
    .commit().then(() => {
        setButtonState(false);
        disabledRef.current = false;
    })
}
```

Comment: with the above code, the like is not working. Adding `<button ref={disabledRef} disabled={buttonState}` makes the button always disabled

Comment: If you are using useRef then you don't need useState.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like your code is working correctly, however because you are waiting for the useState to update, a user can click the button multiple times before the update which produces an unsatisfactory result.

I recommend using useRef instead of useState because of this. They can be confusing if you're not used to them. Here is a codesandbox that I made to answer your question.

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-keller-0s7gi2?file=/src/App.js)

If you want the pure code (and to add support for when the sandbox is removed, here is the basic code used.

```
//add to the top of your script to use useRef
import { useRef } from "react";

 const buttRef = useRef();

  const onButtClick = () => {
    //turns off your button immediately 
    buttRef.current.disabled = true;
    const wait = async () => {
      const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));//remove when you add your await.
      //wait
      await delay(2000);//replace with your await
      //after you are done waiting, turn on the button again.
      buttRef.current.disabled = false;
    };

    wait();
  };

  return <button ref={buttRef} onClick={onButtClick}>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Same as below, this doesn't allow user to like one time also

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'disabled')`

Comment: Are you still using useState? This code works fine if you look at the CodeSandbox that I made. There is no reason for button to be disabled on page load unless you set it as disabled.

Comment: With your error, that means that you are not setting your useRef. Ensure that you assign the useRef to a component like you see in my example and ensure that you are not attempting to run functions on the useRef until the attached component has been rendered.

Comment: I did assign it to the button.

Comment: If you are setting the properties of a null useRef then it has not been assigned yet. Can you share your new code or upload it to a coding website such as CodeSandbox or Replit so we can find the error that you are making?